# How to support Open in feature in iOS App?

Tags: ios, pdf

My app is PDF Reader and i want to support `Open in` feature like when open PDF in Safari , We can open PDF in another PDF Reader app with Open in Feature.

So my app support for `(.PDF)` file and want to show my app on the lists of Open in App like following pic.

I don't know what is that and how to use it?

Please explain or guide me to good tutorials.

Sorry if my question is duplicated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, you only need to register the file types that your app supports. You can check more on

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1